# firebase execute simultaneos operation

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem with my firebase app. My app receive a request and needs to make two operations on firebase in diferrents refs. The problem is that one can fail and the other one does not fail. Is there anyway that I can operate those two queries and if one fail it rollbacks ? Example:

Operations:

```
  //First operation
 database.ref('user/' + id) .push({ id }); //Do not fail
 //Secound operation
 database.ref('userTotalList/).transaction... //Fails
```

I will have the id on user and not on the list. In this case, I need to return an error and cancel the first operation

I think I can do it with transaction but not with diferrents ref, is there anyway to do this on firebase realtime database?

thanks

Comment: [Multi location update](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/09/introducing-multi-location-updates-and_86.html)

Comment: Nice @AndréKool But one of my updates is a transaction. Can it be done with a transaction?

Comment: You can't have a transaction operate on multiple locations.  You have to pick one location, and you can make changes anywhere under it.  All other transactions would have to be at that same location in order for them all to work correctly.